# How to Integrate Karaf in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, apache-karaf

Ok, I am attempting to get the EIK working in Eclipse. I YouTubed the video (it assumes a step I haven't accomplished), googled for awhile, and then just tried to hack it. No dice. Here is the relevant info:

- I have downloaded and installed Karaf. The console works fine.
- I have downloaded EIK.
- I have Eclipse Indigo

  I would appreciate help with these two questions:
- In this video [EIK Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1zVLDwd02Q) They show the user selecting the Apache Karaf OSGi framework from the OSGi Frameworks menu. I have no idea how to get Karafe in there, this is the first blocker.
- I have downloaded EIK and a quick look inside seems to indicate I should copy over into the main Eclipse installation folder. I copied my eclipse folder and tried it out. The Karaf Perspective was not present and I could find no indication that this was installed properly. This my second blocker, getting EIK in Eclipse. I may need to get step one complete before this can happen.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are using Juno I think there is no support for it atm...I am was checking the snapshot repos but I couldn't find any new version...

Comment: It's worth noting, given limited info on this... that Eik does not yet support Karaf 4.x, only 3.x... and fails to work in later Eclipse versions, e.g. Mars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EIK Project moved over to the Apache Karaf space as a separate sub-project. 
The Karaf Team is also working on this for a better integration with Karaf. 
Though right now you probably have to checkout the code and build it on your machine. 
For a better support I suggest to use the users mailing list of the Karaf project.